# Just like IN_ADDRANY can we creat any macro for port number, such that we can bind to any port insteed of a particular port??

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel, multicast

I want to receive the data from different ip addr with different port numbers and the reading the data is in infinite loop?

Comment: *bind to any port* imagine if two programs did this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done.  It would conflict with all other bound sockets on the system.

If what you really want to do is read any traffic coming in through the network interface, you need a packet capture library such as libpcap.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to INADDR_ANY and port 0. The system should pick a free port for you, then.